# Can my third class relic make other items into third class relics?

Tags: relics

I have a third class relic from Blessed Carlo Acutis.  If I touch that item to another item, does that item become a third class relic also?

Answer (score 2):

No

> A third class relic is any item, new or old, that has made contact with the remains of a saint, or pressed against their tomb or reliquary; in other words a first class relic.<sup>1</sup>

> Third-class relics: any object that has been in contact with a first- or second-class relic.<sup>2</sup>

A 3rd class relic doesn't fulfil these requirements.

<sub>1 [Catholic Relics](https://www.scripturecatholic.com/catholic-relics/#:%7E:text=The%20Different%20Classes%20of%20Relics%201%20First%20Class,relic%20that%20the%20Church%20permits%20for%20sale.%20)</sub>

<sub>2 [Wikipedia: Relic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relic#cite_note-39)</sub>